# Merging multi-dimensional hashes in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two hashes which have a structure something similar to this:

```
hash_a = { :a => { :b => { :c => "d" } } }
hash_b = { :a => { :b => { :x => "y" } } }
```

I want to merge these together to produce the following hash:

```
{ :a => { :b => { :c => "d", :x => "y" } } }
```

The merge function will replace the value of :a in the first hash with the value of :a in the second hash. So, I wrote my own recursive merge function, which looks like this:

```
def recursive_merge( merge_from, merge_to )
    merged_hash = merge_to
    first_key = merge_from.keys[0]
    if merge_to.has_key?(first_key)
        merged_hash[first_key] = recursive_merge( merge_from[first_key], merge_to[first_key] )
    else
        merged_hash[first_key] = merge_from[first_key]
    end
    merged_hash
end
```

But I get a runtime error: `can't add a new key into hash during iteration`. What's the best way of going about merging these hashes in Ruby?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you change the first line of recursive_merge to

```
merged_hash = merge_to.clone
```

it works as expected:

```
recursive_merge(hash_a, hash_b)    
->    {:a=>{:b=>{:c=>"d", :x=>"y"}}}
```

Changing the hash as you move through it is troublesome, you need a "work area" to accumulate your results.

Answer (score 11):

Ruby's existing `Hash#merge` allows a block form for resolving duplicates, making this rather simple. I've added functionality for merging multiple conflicting values at the 'leaves' of your tree into an array; you could choose to pick one or the other instead.

```
hash_a = { :a => { :b => { :c => "d", :z => 'foo' } } }
hash_b = { :a => { :b => { :x => "y", :z => 'bar' } } }

def recurse_merge(a,b)
  a.merge(b) do |_,x,y|
    (x.is_a?(Hash) && y.is_a?(Hash)) ? recurse_merge(x,y) : [*x,*y]
  end
end

p recurse_merge( hash_a, hash_b )
#=> {:a=>{:b=>{:c=>"d", :z=>["foo", "bar"], :x=>"y"}}}
```

Or, as a clean monkey-patch:

```
class Hash
  def merge_recursive(o)
    merge(o) do |_,x,y|
      if x.respond_to?(:merge_recursive) && y.is_a?(Hash)
        x.merge_recursive(y)
      else
        [*x,*y]
      end
    end
  end
end

p hash_a.merge_recursive hash_b
#=> {:a=>{:b=>{:c=>"d", :z=>["foo", "bar"], :x=>"y"}}}
```

Comment: "clean monkey-patch"? Isn't that an oxymoron? :-)

Comment: Thanks for this! Perfect solution for my use case with only one tiny modification

Answer (score 8):

You can do it in one line :

```
merged_hash = hash_a.merge(hash_b){|k,hha,hhb| hha.merge(hhb){|l,hhha,hhhb| hhha.merge(hhhb)}}
```

If you want to imediatly `merge` the result into hash_a, just replace the method merge by the method `merge!`

If you are using **rails 3 or rails 4** framework, it is even easier :

```
merged_hash = hash_a.deep_merge(hash_b)
```

or

```
hash_a.deep_merge!(hash_b)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this monkey-patching solution:

```
class Hash
  def recursive_merge(hash = nil)
    return self unless hash.is_a?(Hash)
    base = self
    hash.each do |key, v|
      if base[key].is_a?(Hash) && hash[key].is_a?(Hash)
        base[key].recursive_merge(hash[key])
      else
        base[key]= hash[key]
      end
    end
    base
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to merge one into the other as the ticket suggested, you could modify @Phrogz function

```
def recurse_merge( merge_from, merge_to )
  merge_from.merge(merge_to) do |_,x,y|
    (x.is_a?(Hash) && y.is_a?(Hash)) ? recurse_merge(x,y) : x
  end
end
```

In case there is duplicate key, it will only use the content of `merge_from` hash

Answer (score 0):

Here is even better solution for **recursive merging** that uses **refinements** and has **bang method** alongside with **block support**. This code does work on **pure** Ruby.

```
module HashRecursive
    refine Hash do
        def merge(other_hash, recursive=false, &block)
            if recursive
                block_actual = Proc.new {|key, oldval, newval|
                    newval = block.call(key, oldval, newval) if block_given?
                    [oldval, newval].all? {|v| v.is_a?(Hash)} ? oldval.merge(newval, &block_actual) : newval
                }   
                self.merge(other_hash, &block_actual)
            else
                super(other_hash, &block)
            end
        end
        def merge!(other_hash, recursive=false, &block)
            if recursive
                self.replace(self.merge(other_hash, recursive, &block))
            else
                super(other_hash, &block)
            end
        end
    end
end

using HashRecursive
```

After `using HashRecursive` was executed you can use default `Hash::merge` and `Hash::merge!` as if they haven't been modified. You can use **blocks** with these methods as before.

The new thing is that you can pass boolean `recursive` (second argument) to these modified methods and they will merge hashes recursively.

---

**Example** usage for answering the question. It's extremely easy:

```
hash_a  =   { :a => { :b => { :c => "d" } } }
hash_b  =   { :a => { :b => { :x => "y" } } }

puts hash_a.merge(hash_b)                                   # Won't override hash_a
# output:   { :a => { :b => { :x => "y" } } }

puts hash_a                                                 # hash_a is unchanged
# output:   { :a => { :b => { :c => "d" } } }

hash_a.merge!(hash_b, recursive=true)                       # Will override hash_a

puts hash_a                                                 # hash_a was changed
# output:   { :a => { :b => { :c => "d", :x => "y" } } }
```

For **advanced** example take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49140306/8410844).

Also take a look at my recursive version of `Hash::each`(`Hash::each_pair`) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49167243/8410844).