# Iterate over a deeply nested level of hashes in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, recursion, hash

So I have a hash, and for each level of the hash, I want to store its key and value. The problem is, a value can be another hash array. Furthermore, that hash can contain key value pairs where the value is again another hash array, etc, etc. Also, I won't know how deeply nested each hash will be. To give an example:

```
{
  :key1 => 'value1',
  :key2 => 'value2',
  :key3 => {
     :key4 => 'value4',
     :key5 => 'value5'
   },
    :key6 => {
      :key7 => 'value7',
      :key8 => {
        :key9 => 'value9'
      }
    }
  }
```

..And so on. *What I want to do is save each key, value pair and the id of its parent.* I figure this will probably be done recursively, I'm just unsure how because I'm unfamiliar with recursive functions. I know how to iterate through the data normally:

```
  myHash.each {|key, value|
    ...Do something with the key and value ...
  }
```

And so I'm guessing the recursive call will be something like this:

```
def save_pair (myHash)
  myHash.each {|key, value|
    if(value.class != Hash) ? Pair.create(key, value) : save_pair(value)
  }
end
```

This is untested, and I'm still unsure how to incorporate saving the parent ids regardless.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If I understand the goal, then you should be able to pass in the parent to your save method. For the top level, it will be nil.  The following shows the idea where `puts` is used as a place holder for the "save".

```
def save_pair(parent, myHash)
  myHash.each {|key, value|
    value.is_a?(Hash) ? save_pair(key, value) :
            puts("parent=#{parent.nil? ? 'none':parent}, (#{key}, #{value})")
  }
end
```

Here is an example call to it:

```
hash = Hash.new
hash["key1"] = "value1"
hash["key2"] = "value2"
hash["key3"] = Hash.new
hash["key3"]["key4"] = "value4"
hash["key3"]["key5"] = "value5"
hash["key6"] = Hash.new
hash["key6"]["key7"] = "value7"
hash["key6"]["key8"] = Hash.new
hash["key6"]["key8"]["key9"] = "value9"

save_pair(nil, hash)
```

Answer (score 15):

I know this is a late reply, but I just implemented a non-recursive solution to your problem and thought it is worth sharing.

```
class Hash
  def deep_traverse(&block)
    stack = self.map{ |k,v| [ [k], v ] }
    while not stack.empty?
      key, value = stack.pop
      yield(key, value)
      if value.is_a? Hash
        value.each{ |k,v| stack.push [ key.dup << k, v ] }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Then, coming back to your original problem, you can do:

```
h = {
  :key1 => 'value1',
  :key2 => 'value2',
  :key3 => {
     :key4 => 'value4',
     :key5 => 'value5'
  },
  :key6 => {
    :key7 => 'value7',
    :key8 => {
      :key9 => 'value9'
    }
  }
}
h.deep_traverse{ |path,value| p [ path, value ] }
# => [[:key6], {:key7=>"value7", :key8=>{:key9=>"value9"}}]
#    [[:key6, :key8], {:key9=>"value9"}]
#    [[:key6, :key8, :key9], "value9"]
#    [[:key6, :key7], "value7"]
#    [[:key3], {:key4=>"value4", :key5=>"value5"}]
#    [[:key3, :key5], "value5"]
#    [[:key3, :key4], "value4"]
#    [[:key2], "value2"]
#    [[:key1], "value1"]
```

There is also a [gist version](https://gist.github.com/sepastian/8688143).

Comment: This is exactly of my need! Thank you!

Comment: If you want this to work with all collections, `object.respond_to? :each` or `my_object.class.include? Enumerable` might be used with less hash-specific modification.

Comment: This will traverse in reverse. I assume the OP wants it to traverse in the original order. Change `stack = self.map{ |k,v| [ [k], v ] }` to `stack = self.map{ |k,v| [ [k], v ] }.reverse`

Answer (score 7):

```
class Hash
  def each_with_parent(parent=nil, &blk)
    each do |k, v|
      Hash === v ? v.each_with_parent(k, &blk) : blk.call([parent, k, v])
    end
  end
end

h = { :a => 1, :b => { :c => 3, :d => 4, :e => { :f => 5 } } }

h.each_with_parent { |i| p i }
# [nil, :a, 1]
# [:b, :c, 3]
# [:b, :d, 4]
# [:e, :f, 5]
```

Comment: Is there a way to reassign the results from the loop to the hash?

Comment: I managed by replacing k by v in `v.each_with_parent(k, &blk)` and by doing  p[k] = v.to_i inside the loop. I was trying to reformat a json (changing strings to booleans/integers).

Answer (score 3):

Here is **recursive** (read *improved*) version of `Hash::each`(`Hash::each_pair`) with **block** and **enumerator** support:

```
module HashRecursive
    refine Hash do
        def each(recursive=false, &block)
            if recursive
                Enumerator.new do |yielder|
                    self.map do |key, value|
                        value.each(recursive=true).map{ |key_next, value_next| yielder << [[key, key_next].flatten, value_next] } if value.is_a?(Hash)
                        yielder << [[key], value]
                    end
                end.entries.each(&block)
            else
                super(&block)
            end
        end
        alias_method(:each_pair, :each)
    end
end

using HashRecursive
```

Here are usage **examples** of `Hash::each` with and without `recursive` flag:

```
hash = {
    :a => {
        :b => {
            :c => 1,
            :d => [2, 3, 4]
        },
        :e => 5
    },
    :f => 6
}

p hash.each, hash.each {}, hash.each.size
# #<Enumerator: {:a=>{:b=>{:c=>1, :d=>[2, 3, 4]}, :e=>5}, :f=>6}:each>
# {:a=>{:b=>{:c=>1, :d=>[2, 3, 4]}, :e=>5}, :f=>6}
# 2

p hash.each(true), hash.each(true) {}, hash.each(true).size
# #<Enumerator: [[[:a, :b, :c], 1], [[:a, :b, :d], [2, 3, 4]], [[:a, :b], {:c=>1, :d=>[2, 3, 4]}], [[:a, :e], 5], [[:a], {:b=>{:c=>1, :d=>[2, 3, 4]}, :e=>5}], [[:f], 6]]:each>
# [[[:a, :b, :c], 1], [[:a, :b, :d], [2, 3, 4]], [[:a, :b], {:c=>1, :d=>[2, 3, 4]}], [[:a, :e], 5], [[:a], {:b=>{:c=>1, :d=>[2, 3, 4]}, :e=>5}], [[:f], 6]]
# 6

hash.each do |key, value|
    puts "#{key} => #{value}"
end
# a => {:b=>{:c=>1, :d=>[2, 3, 4]}, :e=>5}
# f => 6

hash.each(true) do |key, value|
    puts "#{key} => #{value}"
end
# [:a, :b, :c] => 1
# [:a, :b, :d] => [2, 3, 4]
# [:a, :b] => {:c=>1, :d=>[2, 3, 4]}
# [:a, :e] => 5
# [:a] => {:b=>{:c=>1, :d=>[2, 3, 4]}, :e=>5}
# [:f] => 6

hash.each_pair(recursive=true) do |key, value|
    puts "#{key} => #{value}" unless value.is_a?(Hash)
end
# [:a, :b, :c] => 1
# [:a, :b, :d] => [2, 3, 4]
# [:a, :e] => 5
# [:f] => 6
```

Here is example from the question itself:

```
hash = {
    :key1   =>  'value1',
    :key2   =>  'value2',
    :key3   =>  {
        :key4   =>  'value4',
        :key5   =>  'value5'
    },
    :key6   =>  {
        :key7   =>  'value7',
        :key8   =>  {
            :key9   =>  'value9'
        }
    }
}

hash.each_pair(recursive=true) do |key, value|
    puts "#{key} => #{value}" unless value.is_a?(Hash)
end
# [:key1] => value1
# [:key2] => value2
# [:key3, :key4] => value4
# [:key3, :key5] => value5
# [:key6, :key7] => value7
# [:key6, :key8, :key9] => value9
```

Also take a look at my recursive version of `Hash::merge`(`Hash::merge!`) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49139981/8410844).

Answer (score 3):

I recomend to use #deep_locate of [hashie gem](https://github.com/intridea/hashie)
https://www.rubydoc.info/github/intridea/hashie/Hashie/Extensions/DeepLocate#deep_locate-instance_method

little bit hacky always return false not to seeking

```
hash.extend(Hashie::Extensions::DeepLocate)
hash.deep_locate -> (key, value, object) do 
  # what you want to do here!
  # key: hash key
  # value: hash value
  # object: hash_object
  false # prevent to stop seeking
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do for JSON well. Minor enhancements to Mark's code where it converts everything to uppercase in a given hash:

```
def capitalize_hash(myHash)
    myHash.each {|key, value|
        puts "isHash: #{value.is_a?(Hash)}: " + value.to_s
        value.is_a?(Hash) ? capitalize_hash(value) : ( value.is_a?(Array) ? (myHash[key] = capitalize_array(value)) : (myHash[key] = value.try(:upcase)))
    }
end

def capitalize_array(myArray)
    myArray.each {|value|
        puts "isHash: #{value.is_a?(Hash)}: " + value.to_s
        value.is_a?(Array) ? capitalize_array(value) : ( value.is_a?(Hash) ? capitalize_hash(value) : value.try(:upcase))
    }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like that?

```
trios = []

def save_trio(hash, parent = nil)
  hash.each do |key, value|
    value.kind_of?(Hash) ? save_trio(value, key) : trios << {:key => key, :value => value, :parent => parent}
  end
end

save_trio(myHash)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to recursively edit the hash, you could do something like this:

```
# Iterates over a Hash recursively
def each_recursive(parent, &block)
  parent.each do |path, value|
    if value.kind_of? Hash
      each_recursive parent, &block
    elsif value.is_a? Array
      # @TODo something different for Array?
    else
      yield(parent, path, container_or_field)
    end
  end
end
```

And you can do something like:

```
hash = {...}
each_recursive(hash) do |parent, path, value|
  parent[path] = value.uppercase
end
```

Comment: Is this a typo? Shouldn't `kind_?` be `kind_of?`

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this issue while trying to convert camel case hash keys to snake case.
that's what I came up with:

```
def hash_to_underscore(hash)
    res = {}
    hash.each do |key, value|
        res[to_underscore(key)] =
        value.instance_of?(Hash) ? hash_to_underscore(value) : value
    end
    res
end

def to_underscore(key)
    key.to_s.underscore.to_sym
end
```