# Ruby: merge nested hash

Tags: ruby, hash, merge, nested

I would like to merge a nested hash.

```
a = {:book=>
    [{:title=>"Hamlet",
      :author=>"William Shakespeare"
      }]}

b = {:book=>
    [{:title=>"Pride and Prejudice",
      :author=>"Jane Austen"
      }]}
```

I would like the merge to be:

```
{:book=>
   [{:title=>"Hamlet",
      :author=>"William Shakespeare"},
    {:title=>"Pride and Prejudice",
      :author=>"Jane Austen"}]}
```

What is the nest way to accomplish this?

Comment: I suggest marking [Jon M's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381553/ruby-merge-nested-hash#9381776) or [Dan's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381553/ruby-merge-nested-hash#30225093) as accepted.

Answer (score 64):

For rails 3.0.0+ or higher version there is the [deep_merge](http://apidock.com/rails/Hash/deep_merge) function for [ActiveSupport](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport) that does exactly what you ask for.

Comment: this does not work. it will replace the existing array with the new array.
http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.13/Hash/deep_merge

It seems to work for Rails 4:
http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/Hash/deep_merge

Comment: No. Although Rails 3.2.18 does have `deep_merge` method, but it accept   a block only from version 4.0.2

Comment: @mirelon The OP didn't ask for the block, so the answer is correct.

Comment: However, the question isn't about Rails, is it? So it's a bit irritating that this answer is the one with the most upvotes.

Answer (score 58):

I found a more generic deep-merge algorithm [here](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/142809), and used it like so:

```
class ::Hash
    def deep_merge(second)
        merger = proc { |key, v1, v2| Hash === v1 && Hash === v2 ? v1.merge(v2, &merger) : v2 }
        self.merge(second, &merger)
    end
end

a.deep_merge(b)
```

Comment: Note: for arrays inside hash, it just overwrites existing array value. S. answer by @Dan for a more sofisticated array handling.

Comment: https://github.com/rubocop/ruby-style-guide#namespace-definition

Answer (score 53):

To add on to Jon M and koendc's answers, the below code will handle merges of hashes, and :nil as above, but it will also union any arrays that are present in both hashes (with the same key):

```
class ::Hash
  def deep_merge(second)
    merger = proc { |_, v1, v2| Hash === v1 && Hash === v2 ? v1.merge(v2, &merger) : Array === v1 && Array === v2 ? v1 | v2 : [:undefined, nil, :nil].include?(v2) ? v1 : v2 }
    merge(second.to_h, &merger)
  end
end


a.deep_merge(b)
```

Answer (score 11):

For variety's sake - and this will only work if you want to merge all the keys in your hash in the same way - you could do this:

```
a.merge(b) { |k, x, y| x + y }
```

When you pass a block to `Hash#merge`, `k` is the key being merged, where the key exists in both `a` and `b`, `x` is the value of `a[k]` and `y` is the value of `b[k]`. The result of the block becomes the value in the merged hash for key `k`.

I think in your specific case though, nkm's answer is better.

Comment: NoMethodError: undefined method `+' for {:color=>"red"}:Hash

Comment: It looks like you are trying to use this answer with a hash containing other keys - `{:color=>"red"}` is not in your example. As I said in my answer, this will only work if you want to merge all the keys in your hash in the same way.

Comment: Perhaps you could add the hash you're working with in full to the question?

Comment: This is actually a pretty handy trick! Had no idea `Hash#merge` took an optional block.

Comment: If merging a hash of keys to arrays, you could do something like this to also merge empty lists: `a.merge(b) { |k, x, y| x + (y ? y : []) }`

Answer (score 8):

A little late to answer your question, but I wrote a fairly rich deep merge utility awhile back that is now maintained by Daniel Deleo on Github: https://github.com/danielsdeleo/deep_merge

It will merge your arrays exactly as you want. From the first example in the docs:

So if you have two hashes like this:

```
   source = {:x => [1,2,3], :y => 2}
   dest =   {:x => [4,5,'6'], :y => [7,8,9]}
   dest.deep_merge!(source)
   Results: {:x => [1,2,3,4,5,'6'], :y => 2}
```

It won't merge :y (because int and array aren't considered mergeable) - using the bang (!) syntax causes the source to overwrite.. Using the non-bang method will leave dest's internal values alone when an unmergeable entity is found. It will add the arrays contained in :x together because it knows how to merge arrays. It handles arbitrarily deep merging of hashes containing whatever data structures.

Lots more docs on Daniel's github repo now..

Answer (score 4):

All answers look to me overcomplicated. Here's what I came up with eventually:

```
# @param tgt [Hash] target hash that we will be **altering**
# @param src [Hash] read from this source hash
# @return the modified target hash
# @note this one does not merge Arrays
def self.deep_merge!(tgt_hash, src_hash)
  tgt_hash.merge!(src_hash) { |key, oldval, newval|
    if oldval.kind_of?(Hash) && newval.kind_of?(Hash)
      deep_merge!(oldval, newval)
    else
      newval
    end
  }
end
```

P.S. use as public, WTFPL or whatever license

Answer (score 2):

Here is even better solution for **recursive merging** that uses **refinements** and has **bang method** alongside with **block support**. This code does work on **pure** Ruby.

```
module HashRecursive
    refine Hash do
        def merge(other_hash, recursive=false, &block)
            if recursive
                block_actual = Proc.new {|key, oldval, newval|
                    newval = block.call(key, oldval, newval) if block_given?
                    [oldval, newval].all? {|v| v.is_a?(Hash)} ? oldval.merge(newval, &block_actual) : newval
                }   
                self.merge(other_hash, &block_actual)
            else
                super(other_hash, &block)
            end
        end
        def merge!(other_hash, recursive=false, &block)
            if recursive
                self.replace(self.merge(other_hash, recursive, &block))
            else
                super(other_hash, &block)
            end
        end
    end
end

using HashRecursive
```

After `using HashRecursive` was executed you can use default `Hash::merge` and `Hash::merge!` as if they haven't been modified. You can use **blocks** with these methods as before.

The new thing is that you can pass boolean `recursive` (second argument) to these modified methods and they will merge hashes recursively.

---

**Example** for simple usage is written at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49139981/8410844). Here is an advanced example.

The example in this question is bad because it got nothing to do with recursive merging. Following line would meet question's example:

```
a.merge!(b) {|k,v1,v2| [v1, v2].all? {|v| v.is_a?(Array)} ? v1+v2 : v2}
```

Let me give you a better example to show the power of the code above. Imagine two rooms, each have one bookshelf in it. There are 3 rows on each bookshelf and each bookshelf currently have 2 books. Code:

```
room1   =   {
    :shelf  =>  {
        :row1   =>  [
            {
                :title  =>  "Hamlet",
                :author =>  "William Shakespeare"
            }
        ],
        :row2   =>  [
            {
                :title  =>  "Pride and Prejudice",
                :author =>  "Jane Austen"
            }
        ]
    }
}

room2   =   {
    :shelf  =>  {
        :row2   =>  [
            {
                :title  =>  "The Great Gatsby",
                :author =>  "F. Scott Fitzgerald"
            }
        ],
        :row3   =>  [
            {
                :title  =>  "Catastrophe Theory",
                :author =>  "V. I. Arnol'd"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

We are going to move books from the shelf in the second room to the same rows on the shelf in the first room. First we will do this without setting `recursive` flag, i.e. same as using unmodified `Hash::merge!`:

```
room1.merge!(room2) {|k,v1,v2| [v1, v2].all? {|v| v.is_a?(Array)} ? v1+v2 : v2}
puts room1
```

The output will tell us that the shelf in the first room would look like this:

```
room1   =   {
    :shelf  =>  {
        :row2   =>  [
            {
                :title  =>  "The Great Gatsby",
                :author =>  "F. Scott Fitzgerald"
            }
        ],
        :row3   =>  [
            {
                :title  =>  "Catastrophe Theory",
                :author =>  "V. I. Arnol'd"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

As you can see, not having `recursive` forced us to throw out our precious books.

Now we will do the same thing but with setting `recursive` flag to *true*. You can pass as second argument either `recursive=true` or just `true`:

```
room1.merge!(room2, true) {|k,v1,v2| [v1, v2].all? {|v| v.is_a?(Array)} ? v1+v2 : v2}
puts room1
```

Now the output will tell us that we actually moved our books:

```
room1   =   {
    :shelf  =>  {
        :row1   =>  [
            {
                :title  =>  "Hamlet",
                :author =>  "William Shakespeare"
            }
        ],
        :row2   =>  [
            {
                :title  =>  "Pride and Prejudice",
                :author =>  "Jane Austen"
            },
            {
                :title  =>  "The Great Gatsby",
                :author =>  "F. Scott Fitzgerald"
            }
        ],
        :row3   =>  [
            {
                :title  =>  "Catastrophe Theory",
                :author =>  "V. I. Arnol'd"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

That last execution could be rewritten as following:

```
room1 = room1.merge(room2, recursive=true) do |k, v1, v2|
    if v1.is_a?(Array) && v2.is_a?(Array)
        v1+v2
    else
        v2
    end
end
puts room1
```

or

```
block = Proc.new {|k,v1,v2| [v1, v2].all? {|v| v.is_a?(Array)} ? v1+v2 : v2}
room1.merge!(room2, recursive=true, &block)
puts room1
```

That's it. Also take a look at my recursive version of `Hash::each`(`Hash::each_pair`) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49167243/8410844).

Answer (score 1):

I think Jon M's answer is the best, but it fails when you merge in a hash with a nil/undefined value.
This update solves the issue:

```
class ::Hash
    def deep_merge(second)
        merger = proc { |key, v1, v2| Hash === v1 && Hash === v2 ? v1.merge(v2, &merger) : [:undefined, nil, :nil].include?(v2) ? v1 : v2 }
        self.merge(second, &merger)
    end
end

a.deep_merge(b)
```

Comment: I don't see issues with `nil` values. Give an example where there is an issue.

Comment: nil.deep_merge({'one'=>'two'})  provokes 'no method 'deep_merge' for 'nil'.

Answer (score -1):

```
a[:book] = a[:book] + b[:book]
```

Or

```
a[:book] <<  b[:book].first
```

Comment: This will work in this particular case, but considering this question's title and its placement in search results, I think we want a generic recursive merge solution here.