# hash.merge with block to add up sub-hash keys?

Tags: ruby, hash

I have read something about hash merge with a block and this is working fine for simple, non-nested hashes in plain ruby. The following code results in `{1=>2, 2=>4, 4=>6}` as expected:

```
a = {1 => 1, 2 => 2, 4 => 3}
b = {1 => 1, 2 => 2, 4 => 3}
a.merge(b) { |key, value_a, value_b | value_a + value_b }
```

But the merge is not working for a nested hash structure, I get a `NoMethodError (undefined method '+' for {1=>1, 2=>2}:Hash)`

```
a = { "2018" => {1 => 1, 2 => 2, 4 => 3} }
b = { "2019" => {1 => 1, 2 => 2, 4 => 3} }
c = a.merge(b) { |key, value_a, value_b | value_a + value_b }
```

I have read about *each_with_object* and I am unsure how to use it. Is there a smart way to accomplish the merge of the values of the sub-hash? What do you think is the easiest way?

Comment: if you are on Rails, try `a.deep_merge(b) { |key, value_a, value_b| value_a + value_b }`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ruby: merge nested hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381553/ruby-merge-nested-hash)

Comment: I am using plain ruby :(

Comment: What would be the expected output for `a.merge(b)` in the second case, it seems there's nothing to merge there as both keys don't coincide.

Comment: [Enumerable#each_with_object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) just saves a couple of steps. If, for example, you wrote `def doit(arr); a = []; arr.each { |n| a << 2*n if n.odd? }; a; end`, you could eliminate the first and last statements by writing `def doit(arr); arr.each_with_object([])  { |n,a| a << 2*n if n.odd? }; end`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nested `Hash`, nested [`Hash#merge`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-merge)?

I changed the key of `b` to `"2018"`

```
a = { "2018" => {1 => 1, 2 => 2, 4 => 3} }
b = { "2018" => {1 => 1, 2 => 2, 4 => 3} }
c = a.merge(b) { |k, v1, v2| v1.merge(v2) { |kk, aa, bb | aa + bb } }

#=> {"2018"=>{1=>2, 2=>4, 4=>6}}
```

For your original values:

```
a = { "2018" => {1 => 1, 2 => 2, 4 => 3} }
b = { "2019" => {1 => 1, 2 => 2, 4 => 3} }
```

The result is

```
#=> {"2018"=>{1=>1, 2=>2, 4=>3}, "2019"=>{1=>1, 2=>2, 4=>3}}
```

Comment: Great simple answer!

Comment: Good answer. Readers: this uses the form of [Hash#merge](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Hash.html#method-i-merge) that employs a block to determine the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged. As seen, this is done at two levels. If `c = { "2018" => {1 => 1, 2 => 2, 4 => 9} }`, with Ruby v2.6 (see linked doc) one can write `a.merge(b, c) { |k, v1, v2| v1.merge(v2) { |kk, aa, bb | aa + bb } } #=> {"2018"=>{1=>3, 2=>6, 4=>15}} `.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Hash#deep_merge](https://apidock.com/rails/Hash/deep_merge) from active support to do this.

```
require 'active_support/all'

a = { k1: { k2: 1 } }
b = { k1: { k2: 2 } }

a.deep_merge(b) { |k, v1, v2| v1 + v2 }
# => { l1: { k2: 3 } }
```