# Merging two hashes with shared root

Tags: ruby, hash

I have:

```
apartment1 = {"base" => {"floor1" => {"apartment1" => {"rooms_number" => 4}}}}
apartment2 = {"base" => {"floor1" => {"apartment2" => {"rooms_number" => 6}}}}
```

that share `{"base" => {"floor1" =>`.

How would I merge the apartments under the shared part to get:

```
{"base" => {"floor1" => {
  "apartment1" => {"rooms_number" => 6},
  "apartment2" => {"rooms_number" => 6}
}}}
```

I merged `apartment1` and `apartment2` into `apartments`, and got this:

```
apartments = {}
apartments.merge!(apartment1)
# => {"base" => {"floor1" => {"apartment1" => {"rooms_number" => 4}}}} 
apartments.merge!(apartment2)
# => {"base" => {"floor1" => {"apartment2" => {"rooms_number" => 6}}}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to merge not at the root level, but at two levels deeper.

```
apartment1.merge(apartment2){|_, h1, h2| h1.merge(h2){|_, h1, h2| h1.merge(h2)}}
# =>
# {"base" => {"floor1" => {
#   "apartment1" => {"rooms_number" => 4},
#   "apartment2" => {"rooms_number" => 6}
# }}}
```

Comment: This is the shortest answer, however, an explanation would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Rails (or in any case if you're willing to use ActiveSupport), you can do this via `deep_merge`:

```rb
2.5.1 :001 > apartment1= {"base" => {"floor1" => {"apartment1" => {"rooms_number" => 4} } }}
 => {"base"=>{"floor1"=>{"apartment1"=>{"rooms_number"=>4}}}} 
2.5.1 :002 > apartment2= {"base" => {"floor1" => {"apartment2" => {"rooms_number" => 6} } }}
 => {"base"=>{"floor1"=>{"apartment2"=>{"rooms_number"=>6}}}} 
2.5.1 :003 > apartments = apartment1.deep_merge apartment2
 => {"base"=>{"floor1"=>{"apartment1"=>{"rooms_number"=>4}, "apartment2"=>{"rooms_number"=>6}}}}
```

See https://apidock.com/rails/Hash/deep_merge

See also this similar question:
[Ruby: merge nested hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381553/ruby-merge-nested-hash)

Answer (score 1):

Handling manually:

```
apartments = apartment1
apartments['base']['floor1'].merge!(apartment2['base']['floor1'])

p apartments
#=> {"base"=>{"floor1"=>{"apartment1"=>{"rooms_number"=>4}, "apartment2"=>{"rooms_number"=>6}}}}
```

Or stealing (!) the algorithm for deep merge from Rails:

```
def deep_merge(first, second)
  first.merge(second) do |key, oldval, newval|
    oldval = oldval.to_hash if oldval.respond_to?(:to_hash)
    newval = newval.to_hash if newval.respond_to?(:to_hash)
    oldval.class.to_s == 'Hash' && newval.class.to_s == 'Hash' ? deep_merge(oldval, newval) : newval
  end
end
```

So you can use it in plain Ruby:

```
deep_merge(apartment1, apartment2) #=> {"base"=>{"floor1"=>{"apartment1"=>{"rooms_number"=>4}, "apartment2"=>{"rooms_number"=>6}}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following recursive method should provide the desired results.

```
def combine_em(arr)
  (k1, k2), (v1, v2) = arr.map(&:flatten).transpose
  (k1==k2 && v1.is_a?(Hash)) ? { k1=>combine_em([v1, v2]) } :
    {}.merge(*arr) 
end
```

```
arr = [{"base"=>{"floor1"=>{"apt1"=>{"room"=>4}}}},
       {"base"=>{"floor1"=>{"apt2"=>{"room"=>6}}}}]
combine_em arr
  #=>  {"base"=>{"floor1"=>{"apt1"=>{"room"=>4},
  #                         "apt2"=>{"room"=>6}}}}

arr = [{"base"=>{"floor1"=>{"level1"=>{"apt1"=>{"room"=>4}}}}},
       {"base"=>{"floor1"=>{"level1"=>{"apt2"=>{"room"=>6}}}}}]
combine_em arr
  #=> {"base"=>{"floor1"=>{"level1"=>{"apt1"=>{"room"=>4},
  #                                   "apt2"=>{"room"=>6}}}}}

arr = [{"base"=>{"floor1"=>{"apt1"=>{"room"=>4}}}},
       {"base"=>{"floor2"=>{"apt1"=>{"room"=>6}}}}]
combine_em arr
  #=>  {"base"=>{"floor1"=>{"apt1"=>{"room"=>4}},
  #              "floor2"=>{"apt1"=>{"room"=>6}}}}
```

```
arr = [{"base"=>{"floor1"=>{"apt1"=>{"room1"=>4}}}},
       {"base"=>{"floor1"=>{"apt1"=>{"room2"=>6}}}}]
combine_em arr
  #=>  {"base"=>{"floor1"=>{"apt1"=>{"room1"=>4,
  #                                  "room2"=>6}}}}
arr = [{"base1"=>{"floor1"=>{"apt1"=>{"room"=>4}}}},
       {"base2"=>{"floor2"=>{"apt1"=>{"room"=>6}}}}]
combine_em arr
  #=> {"base1"=>{"floor1"=>{"apt1"=>{"room"=>4}}},
  #    "base2"=>{"floor2"=>{"apt1"=>{"room"=>6}}}}

arr = [{"base"=>{"floor1"=>{"apt1"=>{"room"=>4}}}},
       {"base"=>{"floor1"=>{"apt1"=>{"room"=>6}}}}]
combine_em arr
  #=>  {"base"=>{"floor1"=>{"apt1"=>{"room"=>6}}}}
```

The last example of `arr` (if it could occur), may not give the desired result. If so, it would be necessary to specify the desired return value in that case.

[Hash#merge](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Hash.html#method-i-merge) was changed in Ruby v2.6 to allow multiple arguments, which is why we can now write

```
arr = [{:a=>1}, {:b=>2}, {:c=>3}]
{}.merge(*arr)
  #=> {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3}
```

To support earlier versions of Ruby, write

```
arr.reduce(&:merge)
```

which is shorthand for

```
arr.reduce { |h,g| h.merge(g) }
```

See [Enumerable#reduce](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) (aka `inject`).

To gain a full understand of how the recursion works it may be necessary to salt the method with `puts` statements.