# How to insert a new hash into existing hash in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I have two hashes:

```
p = {"name"=>"TRICHI", "subdistrict"=>{"WANDIWASH"=>"1234"}}
q = {"name"=>"VELLORE", "subdistrict"=>{"WANDIWASH"=>"4183"}}
```

I need to make this as

```
r = [{"name"=>"VELLORE", "subdistrict"=>{"WANDIWASH"=>"4183"}}, 
    {"name"=>"TRICHI", "subdistrict"=>{"WANDIWASH"=>"1234"}}]
```

Comment: That doesn't seem right, is **r** an array or a hash?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5581285/merging-multi-dimensional-hashes-in-ruby

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you want this:

```
r = [] << p << q
# or r = [p, q]
# either way you'll get:
#  [ {"name"=>"VELLORE", "subdistrict"=>{"WANDIWASH"=>"4183"}},
#    {"name"=>"TRICHI", "subdistrict"=>{"WANDIWASH"=>"1234"}}  ]
```

This way you will have an `array` with 2 `hashes`.

Answer (score 1):

As Tim pointed, r doesn't seem to be a Hash, maybe you meant an Array, in which case you can do

```
r = [p,q]
```

or

```
r = []
r << p
r << q
.. keep going for any other entry you want to push into r
```