# Iterating over the Hash - Ruby

Tags: ruby, hash

This is the correct answer below, but I'm not understanding why it is ok to type "puts word" in the last line, whereas it's not acceptable to type "puts x" since it is defined in almost the exact same way

```
puts "Text please "
text = gets.chomp

words = text.split(" ")
frequencies = Hash.new{0}

words.each { |word| frequencies[word] += 1}

frequencies = frequencies.sort_by { |x, y| y }
frequencies.reverse!
frequencies.each do |word, frequency|
    puts word + " " + frequency.to_s
end
```

Comment: As a tip, when entering a code block you may highlight the whole thing and Ctrl-k to format it as a code block. Or highlight and click the `{}` button in the edit toolbar.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to iterate over a hash in Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227571/how-to-iterate-over-a-hash-in-ruby)

Comment: Not a duplicate of that question - this is actually about variable scope.

Answer (score 2):

It's defined in the same way, as a code block parameter, but not the same **place**. Code blocks can use variables provided as parameters or defined inside themselves, so `puts word` is OK, or in the parent scope (the code which created the block - the "top level" in this case), so `puts frequencies` would also be ok.

However, `x` comes from a completely different code block so the block at the bottom doesn't know about it. `x` only has meaning within the block that you pass to `frequencies.sort_by`.

Comment: Ah, I see. So if the third to last line said `do |x, frequency|`, `puts x` would be acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

It's not defined in the same way.

x is defined in the sort_by block of frequencies.

It's not defined there.

It would work if you had put instead:

```
frequencies.each do |x, y|
    puts x + " " + y.to_s
end
```

for example, but x and y aren't defined outside of {}, or in this case, do...end

Comment: So it is alright to say "puts word" because it is a placeholder in the .each block?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confused on the scope of your placeholders. On the last line you use `|word,frequency|` as your placeholders in `frequencies.each do |word, frequency|`, whereas your `|x,y|` is scoped to your first `each` in  `frequencies = frequencies.sort_by { |x, y| y }`

As an aside, perhaps it would be best if you renamed your `|x, y|` to something specific? You can get lost in code if you don't properly define your variables, methods, placeholders etc. Just a thought.