# Chef Attributes, How to get the value of a specific key

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I'm trying to manage a chef role as below.
In this case the attribute node["customer"]["name"] is an array. 
In the recipe I need to get the value of the first element of the array node["customer"]["name"] as "foo".

```
"customer" => {
    "name" => {
        ["foo"] => {
            "prod" => {
                "apache" => {
                    "listening" => 81
                },
                "database" => {
                    "type" => "postgres"
                }
            },
            "dev" => {
                "apache" => {
                    "listening" => 81
                },
                "database" => {
                    "type" => "postgres"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I have done:

```
node[:customer][:name].each do |customer|
Chef::Log.info("CONFIGURING --- #{customer}")
end
```

But unexpectly, the variable "customer" contain the value

> INFO: CONFIGURING --- ["[\"foo\"]",
>   {"prod"=>{"apache"=>{"listening"=>81},
>   "database"=>{"type"=>"postgres"}},
>   "dev"=>{"apache"=>{"listening"=>81},
>   "database"=>{"type"=>"postgres"}}}]

instead of just simple value "foo"

How can i get the simple value "foo" instead of the whole recursive hash?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to iterate over a hash in Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227571/how-to-iterate-over-a-hash-in-ruby)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
node[:customer][:name].each do |customer,properties|
  Chef::Log.info("CONFIGURING --- #{customer}")
end
```

You're just using ruby there to iterate over a hash, you have to tell ruby you don't wish to get the full object but just the key and something else to get the rest of the properties.

Comment: This seems to be the solution, even if the variable need to be cleaned from " and [] chars

Comment: @marcogiusti the values are what the one you provided, if you want to get `["Foo"]` or only `FOO` is your  responsibility

Comment: I mean, remove the [] if you don't want it to be taken as an array and you'll get FOO

Comment: in my case i need to manage it as array coz multiple roles binded to the node need to not overwrite themself as "customer"

Comment: And ? a hash is just a associative array. here you're not creating an array, you're just saying this entry is `["FOO"]` litteraly as the key. `"names" => {"foo" => {} }; names << {"toto" => {}}` will give you the same as `"names" => { "foo" => {}, "toto" => {}}`. I highly advise you reading about hashes (as the deep-merge done by chef is more or less calls to the `<<` operator at end.). What denotes a hash, is the `{}` for it's value, what denotes an array is the `[]` in it's value. `"name" => { ["toto"] => {}}`is just telling that the first key of names is ["toto"].

Comment: If you want `name` to be an array it should be `"name" => ["foo" => {}, "toto" => {}]`. and in this case `name[0]`would return "foo" hash, and you'll still have to derive it if you want to get it's name as a key. (kind of nonsense IMHO)

Comment: Using this method, the problem, I assume right now, is impossible to retrieve other attributes as "node[customer][name][foo][prod][apache][listening]"
chef give me error as null attribute

Comment: @MarcoGiusti Indeed, it will become `node['customer']['name'][0]['prod']['apache']....`. That's why I said you're going the wrong path wishing an array. Please open a new question if there's another problem, but take time to understand hashes and how to iterate over them in ruby. Many community cookbooks already use this syntax, that's a correct starting point to understand how they're accessed and populated.

Comment: Thanks Tensibai for all the help here, I will go deeper as you mentioned.

Answer (score -1):

One cannot have an array implemented in Chef roles. Chef roles can have only attributes set to some value. For example below should work fine.

```
"customer" => {
    "name" => "foo"
}
```

Comment: This is not true, arrays of attributes are allowed in roles.

Comment: I confirm, the attributes are a hash but you can have an array (or many) inside this hash