# ruby - iterate through a hash containing key/array value pairs, and iterate through each value

Tags: ruby

I have an hash that looks like this:

```
{
  "key1": [
     "value1",
     "value2",
     "value3"
  ],
  "key2": [
     "value1",
     "value2",
     "value3",
     "value4",
     "value5"
  ],
  "key3": [
     "value1"
  ],
  "key4": [
     "value1",
     "value2"
  ]
}
```

How do I iterate through every keyN, while also looping through all the values in that key?

I have an array with all the keys if that helps.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to iterate over a hash in Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227571/how-to-iterate-over-a-hash-in-ruby)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Pretty simple, really:

```
hash.each do |name, values|
  values.each do |value|
    # ...
  end
end
```

You can do whatever you want with `name` and `value` at the lowest level.

Comment: indeed simple - was looking at it the wrong way. thanks

Comment: Once you get the hang of it, you'll find this pattern works in a variety of situations. `.each` is the backbone of most Ruby applications.

Answer (score 4):

If you are sure about the size of arrays, simply you can do like this,

```
ha = {:a => [1,2]}

ha.each do |k, (v1, v2)|
   p k
   p v1
   p v2
end

Output
:a
1
2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
hash.each do |key, array|
  array.each do |value|
    # do something
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
hash.each do |key_N, values_N|
  values_N.each so |values|
  .
  .
  #YourCode
  .
  .
  end
end
```

Comment: Names like `keyN` should be `key_n` to follow Ruby convention. Capital letters have significant meaning, especially when it comes to `CONSTANT_NAMES` and `ClassNames`.

Comment: @tadman Thank you for pointing that out. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Getting there. Generally capitals are avoided entirely in variable names, it just confuses things.

Comment: Not `so` but `do`.