# How can I extract just the ids from an array of hashes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to iterate over this data to extract the value of the ids:

```
[ {:id => 3, :quantity => 5 }, { :id => 4, :quantity => 3 } ]
```

Comment: This is a low-quality question, but it is *not* an exact duplicate of [this other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227571/how-to-iterate-over-a-hash-in-ruby) low-quality question. It needs a better close target; voting to reopen.

Comment: I guess it's not an exact duplicated but are we letting it opened anyway? Actually the accepted answer is the same in the other question...

Comment: I don't understand why my question sucked, but you took the time to answer, @CodeGnome, and 5 people voted on the answer (I'm assuming it was helpful for five people). It was a basic question and very simple. Do you want me to ask complex questions? The other question posted was similar than mine, but also different and is not what I needed.

Comment: @myhouse It's low quality because it doesn't show much research effort, and while it provides a corpus there's no code showing what you've done to solve the problem. The question was at least *clear*, so I don't really have a problem with it. However, be aware that trivial questions, especially those that don't show where you're struggling with code or error messages, tend to be downvoted. YMMV.

Comment: I wasn't sure how to grab the hashes inside of the array. I tried doing ar.each do |k, v| and printing out separately like people were doing in the other question but it wouldn't produce the expected results. I wanted someone to quickly show me something really basic and I got what I needed. I think the down comment was kinda a jerk move.

Comment: @JorgedelosSantos Questions shouldn't be marked duplicates because of similar (or even identical) answers. You can find related posts about this on meta. Questions should be marked duplicates when the *question* is substantially the same.

Comment: @myhouse See? That would have been helpful in avoiding close votes, since it would show why the other question is *not* a duplicate of yours. The questions have different data sets, and different objectives, even though both involve hashes.

Comment: This only has been out for 4 hours and 8 people found it useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[ {:id => 3, :quantity => 5 }, { :id => 4, :quantity => 3 } ].each do |hash|
  puts hash[:id]
end
```

This will `puts` each id value on the screen. You can do what you need to do from there.

Answer (score 5):

You can use Array's `map` method like below:

```
arr =[ {:id => 3, :quantity => 5 }, { :id => 4, :quantity => 3 } ]
ids = arr.map { |k| k[:id] }
#=> [3,4]
```

Comment: There is a small typo error in your answer. Should be 
`ids = arr.map{ |k| k[:id] }`

Answer (score 1):

### Ruby: Mapping Over an Array with Hash#values_at

There's more than one way to do this in Ruby. A lot depends on what you're trying to express. If you're not trying to play code golf, one way to do this is with [Hash#values_at](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-values_at). For example:

```
[{id: 3, quantity: 5}, {id: 4, quantity: 3}].flat_map { |h| h.values_at :id }
#=> [3, 4]
```

### Rails: Extracting Data with Pluck

A more Rails-like way would be to just [ActiveRecord::Calculations#pluck](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#pluck) the attributes you want in the query itself. For example:

```
Stuff.where(quantity: [3, 5]).pluck :id
```

There are certainly other ways to get the same result. Your mileage may vary, depending on your real use case.

### See Also

[*Active Record Query Interface*](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#pluck)