# Rails iterate multiple hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash

I have the following hash :

```
{
  "2017-01-01" => {
    "2"=> [
      {:a=>"2017-01-01", :b=>"2", :c=>"1"},
      {:a=>"2017-01-01", :b=>"2", :c=>"2"}
    ]
  },
  "2017-01-02" => {
    "5"=> [
      {:a=>"2017-01-02", :b=>"5", :c=>"1"}
    ]
  }
}
```

I would iterate separately

1)first iteration

```
{
 {:a=>"2017-01-01", :b=>"2", :c=>"1"},
 {:a=>"2017-01-01", :b=>"2", :c=>"2"}
}
```

2) second iteration

```
{
 {:a=>"2017-01-02", :b=>"5", :c=>"1"}
}
```

How can I do? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok, and what have you tried so far to solve this? Stackoverflow is not a code-writing service.

Comment: I have trouble understanding the iteration operation of multiple hash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

answer for your question is in [How to iterate over a hash in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227571/how-to-iterate-over-a-hash-in-ruby) 
check it.

```
hash.each do |key, array|
  puts array
end
```

if 'array' again is a hash, then you need to loop it as follows

```
hash.each do |key, hash2|
  hash2.each do |key2,array|
    puts array
  end 
end
```

Comment: If I want print only the key ":a" ?

Comment: @DomenicoGarofoli you may need to loop array as      array.each{|elem| puts elem[0]}