# How can i get elements of an dinamic payload?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can i get the attributes of this payload?, one, two, three are not static attributes, they could be whatever, now i want to get the  `"one": "1"`,  `"two": "2"`,...

```
{
 "section": "factor",
 "data": {
    "one": "1",
    "two": "2",
    "three": "3"
  }
}
```

my attempt is params[:data][1], but how to know if there is the element [1]...

i need to iterate, how to get the key and value

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227571/how-to-get-a-specific-output-iterating-a-hash-in-ruby

Answer (score 1):

The following would be working:

```
payload = {
  "section": "factor",
  "data": {
    "one": "1",
    "two": "2",
    "three": "3"
  }
}

data = payload[:data]

data.each_pair do |key,value|
  puts "#{key}:#{value}"
end
```